# Solution of differential equation $x'=\cos(x),$ with condition $x(0)=0$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, picard-scheme

> Write out the Picard iteration scheme. If possible, find the solution.
>
> $x'=cos(x),x(0)=0$

I did the picard iterations but I don't know how to get the solution from this

$$u_0=0,...,u_3=\int_0^t\cos(\sin(s))ds$$

I know the solution is this

The solution to the IVP is $x(t)=2\tan^{-1}(\tanh(\frac t2))$

Comment: Such iterations converge to a solution but they do not give you an explicit solution. To get it, it is best to notice that $\frac{x'}{\cos(x)}=1$ is a separable DE. All you have to do is to find a primitive of $\frac{1}{\cos x}$ and the inverse function of such primitive.

Comment: So, are you able to compute $\int_{0}^{t}\frac{d\theta}{\cos\theta}$ for any $t\in(0,\pi/2)$? Suggestion: enforce the substitution $\theta=2\arctan u$.

Comment: I have the solution of $\int \frac{d\theta}{\cos\theta}$ is $ln |sec \theta + tan \theta| + C $ but how do I evaluate in the interval $(0,\pi /2)$?. $tan\theta$ is not defined in $\pi /2$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio why do I have to solve the equation in that way, i.e. to find the primitive of  $\frac{1}{\cos x}$ and then the inverse?

Comment: Because that is the general method for solving a separable DE of the $\frac{x'}{g(x)}=1$ kind. Do you really went straight to implementations of Picard's algorithm, without the background theory on separable DEs, the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem and so on?